# FTP an entire folder via the command line

Tags: ssh, centos, ftp, mirror

I'm looking so migrate some websites to a new server.
I have SSH access to the current one but only FTP access to the new one.

How can I via Centos and SSH copy entire folders to the new server via FTP?

I can log into the new server via the built in FTP client on Centos but I'm not sure of the commands after this.
I need to move the httpdocs folder from the old to the public_html folder of the new server.

I'd love to do this server to server as it'll be a lot quicker than download -> upload via my broadband connection.

Yours,
Chris

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you can install lftp on the server you have SSH to, try its mirror command:

```
mirror -R /path/to/httpdocs /path/to/public_html_on_destination_machine
```

Comment: Very cool thanks, seems to work and for all the Googling in the world I couldn't find that!

Answer (score 2):

`ncftp` works well too with `get -R`

Answer (score 0):

Tar/gzip the files and send them that way - you will benefit from compression that you wouldn't have otherwise had, and you may find it easier to preserve permissions.